# Rauch section: determining output voltage when we have a constant input

Tags: operational-amplifier

I was asked to determine the output voltage for a constant input of the following Rauch section [image]

(note that the input is on the left and the output is on the right)

This is looking too easy, that's why I'm questioning myself. If we put a constant input the capacitors behave as open-circuits. Therefore the mesh containing the input voltage is decoupled from the circuit. Therefore everything on the left of \$R_7\$ can be ignored. Now \$R_7\$ is the only thing connected to one of the op amp inputs. That means the current through \$R_7\$ is zero, and we can replace it with a short-circuit.
Therefore we can use KVL equations and determine the output voltage

$$V_{\text{out}}=R_9 I$$
$$12=(R_8+R_9)I$$

And that means that \$V_{\text{out}}=6\text{V}\$. 
Is this correct? It seems correct but I feel that I'm missing something. I know that in my analysis I'm only using the "ideal op amp" model, but I guess that's what we're supposed to do.

Comment: Seems right, assuming the lower input is the non-inverting input so that the op amp is configured with negative feedback (the inputs aren't labeled).

Comment: Yes it is! But by the way what difference would it make in this case? Both input current are zero and the voltage between them is also zero.

Comment: If the inputs are swapped such that there is positive feedback you can no longer assume the inputs are at the same voltage. The op amp would be saturated, and the output would be as close to either 0V or 12V that the 741 can drive to.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much for your explanation!

Comment: Why is a grounding symbol being used for a VCC?

Comment: @VoltageSpike I didn't draw the circuit, my professor did, but it is a poor choice indeed.